# Rewrite Rule not Working in IIS Server with PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, iis, url-rewriting

Hi, friends. I'm creating an .htaccess file with rewrite rules. It's working fine in localhost, but on the live, server it's not working. My hosting uses a Window server.

I wrote this Rule in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project_name/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !example.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$

RewriteRule (.*) pages.php?page_slug=$1 [L]
```

Comment: `.htaccess` is a file proprietary to Apache httpd. IIS uses a different approach. Have a look at [this](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) and other pages linked there.

Comment: You need to write those rules in the `web.config` file at the root of your website (supposing your host has the module available).

Answer (score 0):

For the case of wordpress to run on IIS server , you need to create web.config in root directory then put the code below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="wordpress" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```